# Salesforce Snapin Survey

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, liveagent, livechattranscript

Is there anyway to implement post chat survey in salesforce Snap-in chat?

Thanks for your thoughts and answers.

Comment: Hey Kumara, it's great that you've added a bounty to your question, but you're even more likely to get a conclusive response if you can [flesh out your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Right now, it's very broad and inspecific, and doesn't show any work that you may have done to date.

Comment: This is a research question as i am unable to enable the post chat survey in Salesforce Snap-in chat through configuration.I am trying to figure out is there anyway to code this in.

Comment: If you have made any efforts to solve this question yourself, your post will be much better received if you **[edit]** it to describe them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has a [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205353&type=1) on this subject. I'm including the most pertinent information here in case the link goes dead. The main point to consider here is that the user will be following a link to a survey and that can be a custom Visualforce page or something else from an AppExchange package.

> **Post-chat Survey Integration**
>
> To implement a Live Agent Post-chat page
> follow the click path below:
>
> 1. Go to *Setup* | *Chat Buttons & Invitations* | setup either a **New** or you can use an existing one.
> 2. When implementing a survey into the Post-chat page, you will want to paste the link to the survey into the *Post-Chat URL* field, which is
>    located at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce does not provide any direct documentation for this, what worked for me.

- Implement either a Salesforce Community or Salesforce site.com, create a post chat visualforce page and include it in the site/community. Make the access public and on mobile, etc.
- Go to your site setting (salesforce) change Clickjack Protection Level to "Allow framing of site or community pages on external domains (Good protection)"
- Add your website to Whitelisted Domains for Inline Frames in site setting page, this needs to be the webpage where the embedded service is hosted.
- Add the force.com site URL (which should be accessible without login/as public) to the chat button Post Chat URL eg.https://*.force.com//